# How to update data on change when using TemplateRef from parent component in child in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a child component which renders template from parent like embededView.

```
exports class ParentComponent {
   public someProp: string;

   ngOnInit() {
      this.someHttpFunc();
   }

   public someHttpFunc() {
      // make some http call and update this.someProp
   }
}
```

```
exports class ChildComponent {
   @Input() someRef: TemplateRef<any>
   @ViewChild("content", { read: ViewContainerRef }) contentRef: ViewContainerRef;

   ngOnInit() {
     this.contentRef.createEmbeddedView(someRef);
   }
}
```

My parent.component.html:

```
<child someRef="template"></child>
<ng-template #template>

  <div>{{ someProp }}</div>
</ng-template>
```

My child.component.html

```
<div #content></div>
```

The problem is that when the http call in `someHttpFunc()` finish the result of someProp in the child component is not automatically updated. When I set timeout for `this.contentRef.createEmbeddedView(someRef);`
everything works fine, but definitely it's not a good solution

Comment: Use an observable instead `{{ someProp$ | async }}`

Comment: I am already using observable, `someProp` is the name of property which will be updated in `.subscribe()`

Comment: Welcome to change detection in Angular. It's a broader topic that requires an understanding of how it works, and you should learn that first before you get into more advantage techniques of cross referencing templates between components. The `async` pipe will mark the **view** as dirty when the observable emits a value. This was my *quick fix* for you, because guess who's view needs updating? The `ChildComponent` which is where the **instance** of the `async` pipe will run. `ParentComponent` does not render the template. So no expressions have changed to mark the view dirty.

Comment: I recommend you read this: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-change-detection-in-angular

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

parent.component.ts

```
exports class ParentComponent {
   public someProp$: Observable<string>;
   private propSource: Subject<string>;

   constructor() {
     this.propSource = new Subject();
     this.someProp$ = this.propSource.asObservable();
   }
   ngOnInit() {
      this.someHttpFunc();
   }

   public someHttpFunc() {
      // psuedo code for http calls
      httpCall.subscribe(() => {
        const newValue = 'x'; // here it's the new value of your props
        this.propSource.next(newValue)
      });
   }
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<child someRef="template"></child>
  <ng-template #template>

  <div>{{ someProp$ | async }}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try using setter , like these code

```js
exports class ChildComponent {
  @Input()
  set someRef(newTemplate: TemplateRef < any > ) {
    if (!newTemplate) {
      return;
    }

    this.contentRef.createEmbeddedView(someRef);

  }

  @ViewChild("content", {
    read: ViewContainerRef
  }) contentRef: ViewContainerRef;
}
```